# On clicking a menu item on Toolbar shows a List view

Tags: android, android-studio

I am expecting this kind of output 
[image]

I can add menu items on a toolbar but no idea how to show a list by clicking one of those items.
Specifically, I mean if I click one of those menu items,
[image] 
it should pop up a dialog/list just shown in above image.
A little guide might help me pass through this confusion.

Comment: You need to create an options menu.
This will then handle your onClick events from those actionbar buttons.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PopupMenu is what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

If you want action overflow icon with hidden menu items set in your inflated menu.xml file showAsAction to never:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate_me"
    android:title="@string/rate_me"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    />
```